# Variant named 'debug-x86' but only variants named '' were found

Tags: android, android-studio

After upgrading to Android Studio 3.5 Canary 1 (but keeping the Android Gradle Plugin version at an older version 3.4.1), I started getting this error:

```
ERROR: Variant named 'debug-x86' but only variants named '' were found.
```

The "Build Variants" window is empty, stuck at "Loading" state. Sync, refresh C++ project, build, etc. don't work.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by: 
   1. Upgrading to Android Studio 3.6 Canary 3, and
   2. Invalidate Caches and Restart.